# Не находит папку media на хостинге django

Tags: django

Задеплоил django проект на хостинг pythonanywhere, но он не находит media, выдавая ошибку:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/milleniax/media/photo_2019-10-27_17-24-37.jpg'
```

Папка media лежит по адресу: `'/home/milleniax/resizing_api/media'`

Ссылка на сайт для полноты ошибки: http://milleniax.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: Пути отличаются. Вот и не находит...

Comment: Блин ну это понятно. Почему он ищет по этому пути?

Comment: Проверьте `MEDIA_ROOT` и `MEDIA_URL` в `settings.py`. Также ошибка может быть в шаблоне, хорошо бы привести его в вопрос (нажав кнопку [edit]).

Answer (score 1):

в **settings.py** напиши

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

а в **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

в urls.py лучше сделать так:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]